# Alias wordpress folder from within another website

Tags: php, nginx, wordpress

I have a little dilemma. I wrote a custom PHP MVC framework and built a CMS on top of it. I decided to give nginx+fpm a whirl too. Which is the root of my dilemma. I was asked to incorporate a wordpress blog into my website (yah.) It has much content and it's not feasible in the short amount of time I have to bring all the content into my CMS. Because of using Apache for years, I'm, admittedly, a little lost using nginx.

My website has the file path:

```
/opt/directories/mysite/public/
```

The wordpress files are located at:

```
/opt/directories/mysite/news/
```

I know I just need to setup location(s) that targets /news[/*] and then forces all matching URI's to the index.php within. Can someone point me in the right direction perhaps?

My configuration is below:

```
server {

        listen   80;
        server_name staging.mysite.com

        index   index.php;

        root /opt/directories/mysite/public;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/mysite/access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/mysite/error.log;

        add_header  X-NodeName  directory01;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?route=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ /news {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @news;
        }

        location @news {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/news)(/.*)$;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /opt/directories/mysite/news/index.php;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }

        include fastcgi_params;
        include php.conf;

        location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
                access_log        off;
                expires           30d;
        }

        ## Disable viewing .htaccess & .htpassword
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny  all;
        }
}
```

My php.conf file:

```
location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
        fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

        fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx;

        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
        fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;

    # If you must use PATH_INFO and PATH_TRANSLATED then add 
    # the following within your location block above 
    # (make sure $ does not exist after \.php or /index.php/some/path/ will not match):

    #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO          $fastcgi_path_info;
    #fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED    $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
}
```

fastcgi_params file:

```
fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
```

Thanks, in large part, to @Kromey, I have adjusted my location /news/ but I am still not getting the desired result.

I was able to learn to tack a ~ my /news location as I discovered that my php location was being matched first.

With this setup, I now get a 200 status, but the page is blank. Any ideas?

Comment: I did not take this problem to completion. I had issues with the wordpress installation itself. They were of a php-fpm kind and had nothing to do with nginx. I ended up doing a load balanced proxy from two other apache hosts. This works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite simple, and a heckuva lot more compact than the similar setup for Wordpress on Apache (I run 2 Wordpress blogs, both previously on Apache and both recently migrated to nginx+PHP (not FPM, although I did have that running for a time before deciding it was overkill for my low-traffic sites)).

```
location /news/ {
    #Need a new root to point to your "aliased" directory
    root /opt/directories/news
    # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

As the comment implies, any static content (images, CSS, JavaScript, robots.txt, etc.) that lives inside your Wordpress path gets served directly, with no PHP involvement; *everything* else gets routed to index.php.

Note that the `try_files` directive is semi-new (0.8 I think?), so you may have to upgrade your nginx; when I installed from the Ubuntu apt repositories, it was too old a version to do this, and the configuration was so much more complex that I `apt-get remove`d it and installed nginx from source (a rather simple operation).

Comment: Ah crud, I am using the Debian package. It shows...
`nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/0.6.32`
Thanks for your help @Kromey. You rock! 
Better figure out how to upgrade.

Comment: Yeah, I very strongly suggest you remove it and then install from source. It's not hard to do at all, and keeps your Wordpress config quite simple. The alternative involves ugly if statements (which the nginx community tries to avoid like the plague); see this link, although you'll of course have to change the location and paths for your environment: http://joneslee85.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/howto-nginx-wordpress-ubuntu-shortest-setup/

Comment: Thanks, I was able to build a custom Debian package (which is nice because I can quickly deploy to my farm servers.) The link is http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/666 btw. I got it installed and I'm about to test it with the config you gave me.

Comment: Just for documentation sake. After installing my new Debian package and trying to restart, I got the following error:
`directory01:~/src# /etc/init.d/nginx restart
Restarting nginx: [emerg]: mkdir() "/usr/local/nginx/uwsgi_temp" failed (2: No such file or directory)
nginx.
` I just had to make the folder `mkdir -p /usr/local/nginx/uwsgi_temp` and nginx restarted fine.

Comment: @Kromey, any idea why I get:
`No input file specified.`
When I surf to:
`http://mysite.tld/news/`
?
Just for fun, I entered the following in my console:
`cat /opt/directories/news/index.php`
The contents of the WP index.php file are shown.

Comment: Just to summarize. I upgrade to the latest stable version of nginx (0.85.) The try directive works, however, I get a 404 with the not-so-enlightening error message `No input file specified.` that comes with a 404. I assumed that try lets the page return errors. With the 404, I guess that's understandable. Do I need to change the root for my location? I have the original root in server scope. How else can I get my images, etc?
Thanks.

Comment: Ah, right, your $document_root and the location of your Wordpress PHP files is different. You have two options: Put a new root directive inside your `location /news/` block, or else put this inside the same block: `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /opt/directories/news/$fastcgi_script_name`

Comment: Either way this did not work. I have updated my config in my question (after "UPDATE") I tried using try_files for the root website as well. So far I still get a 404 error with "No input file specified."

Comment: @Bretticus First thing, move your `root` directive out of your `location /` block; `root` should always be defined in the `server` block. Leave the `root` directive in the `location /news/` where it is, however. You can then reset your `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` to use the $document_root variable as you had originally.

Comment: @Kromey Thanks so much for continuing to help me. I moved location / to use the rewrite again (I need a rewrite with my ?route=$1 configured.) 

Is my updated configuration in line with what you meant? Perhaps not as I still get a 404 error when surfing to /news/.

Thanks again!

Comment: @Bretticus Your try_files should go to just /index.php, as the root automatically gets prepended to that (that was my error in my answer, sorry). Also (but you'll need to verify this, sorry don't have nginx documentation handy) I believe the root directive should *not* have a trailing / on it. Finally, remove the fastcgi_param from your `location /news/` block, that's already being correctly handled (thanks to the change in root) in your php.conf. I've updated the code in my answer to more closely/correctly show what you need.

Comment: @Kromey Thanks again for the tip. I've adjusted my code as you suggested. Unfortunately, /news still gives a 404 "Content not Found" header" (I get a blank.) Oddly /news/ passes through to my CMS (the public/index.php file.)  I'm pretty sure that both are hitting the CMS actually as I just confirmed a bogus uri returns the same header as /news. /news/ pulls up my homepage for the CMS (which means it is happening in the location /news/ block otherwise /news/ would generate a 404 same as /news.) The difference is that /news appears to be hitting the location / block. Why is /news/ ignoring root?

Comment: Just wanted to note that try_files is working fine in the standalone version of the website. I think, perhaps, I'm going to drop a new folder in the same root and use a rewrite since I will have /news and the standalone website using the same database (hope wp-config.php will let me override URL.)

Comment: @Bretticus Okay, I think I see what's happening now. nginx will only ever match a request to a single `location` block (although `try_files` seems to make it try again?), and regex matches (such as that in your php.conf file) will take precedence over simple strings (such as that in your `location /news/` block). We can override this, though: change `location /news/` to `location ^~ /news/`; this will force nginx to stop looking once it matches that, and use that block. If this still doesn't work, though, I suggest you head over to the nginx community. http://wiki.nginx.org/Community

Comment: Hi @kromey, I happened to discover your tip with force-matching a location (I used ~.) This seems to work, however I now end up with a blank page. See my config above one more time if you don't mind.
Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Bretticus The ~ means case-sensitive matching; the ^~ on the other hand stops the search once that string matches. Also, you should have a trailing slash on `location ^~ /news/`. Move all of your fastcgi_params outside of the `location` block so they're valid for the whole server (you're missing a few necessary ones, like REQUEST_URI, for /news/); then, in the @news location, override *only* the script filename, you don't want the path info stuff (but keep the fastcgi_pass). Good change to use the named location in your `try_files` directive, I think you're almost there!